# Get the magnitude of a vector (x,y)

Tags: python, python-2.7, oop, vector

I'm struggling to get this to work because all the answers I can find that most answers are more focused on vectors in numpy arrays and not like mine in classes (OOP). (I hope I am phrasing all this the correct way, please excuse if I am not).

I want to find the magnitude of a vector (x,y), here is my code:

```
class Vector(object):

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
```

I have code that can sum and subtract the two vectors, but how to get the magnitude with this equation:

magnitude = math.sqrt(sum(v**2 for v in vector))

This is my code but it is not giving me what I need:

```
def vector_mag(self):
        x_vector = self.x
        y_vector = self.y
        vector = (x_vector, y_vector)
        magnitude = math.sqrt(sum(v**2 for v in vector))
        return Vector(magnitude)
```

This gives an error that says:

> line 22, in
>
> print vector.vector_mag()
>
> line 14, in vector_mag
>
> return Vector(magnitude)
>
> TypeError: **init**() takes exactly 3 arguments (2 given)

So when I add another "string" in the return part like this...:

> return Vector("Vector magnitude is:", magnitude)

...the program runs but gives a strange result.

What am I doing wrong?

Here is my "full" code:

> import math
>
> class Vector(object):
>
> ```
>   def __init__(self, x, y):
>        self.x = x
>        self.y = y
>
>   def vector_mag(self):
>        x_vector = self.x
>        y_vector = self.y
>        vector = (x_vector, y_vector)
>        magnitude = math.sqrt(sum(v**2 for v in vector))
>        return Vector("Vector magnitude is: ", magnitude)
> ```
>
> vector1 = Vector(10, 1)
>
> vector2 = Vector(20, 2)
>
> vector_list = [(vector1), (vector2)]
>
> for vector in vector_list:
>
> ```
>  print vector.vector_mag()
> ```

Comment: Why do you want to return another vector from `vector_mag` call? Shouldn't it be, well, a number?

Comment: You're right tukasz, I was just stupid there, thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define `vector_mag` like so:

```
def __abs__(self):
    return (self.x ** 2 + self.y ** 2) ** 0.5
```

Then calling your method is as easy as this:

```
vector1 = Vector(10, 1)
print 'Magnitude =', abs(vector1)
```

Answer (score 4):

For accuracy reason, you should use [math hypot](https://docs.python.org/library/math.html#math.hypot) to avoid any overflow.

```
from math import hypot

def __abs__(self):
    return hypot(self.x, self.y)
```

> `math.hypot(x, y)`: Return the Euclidean norm, `sqrt(x*x + y*y)`. This is the length of the vector from the origin to point (x, y).

This would give:

```
from math import hypot
class Vector(object):

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
    def __abs__(self):
        return hypot(self.x, self.y)

v=Vector(3,1)
magnitude = abs(v)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
return Vector(magnitude)
```

The magnitude of a vector is a scalar value; in other words, it's a single number. A vector is a collection of numbers, so it doesn't make sense to try to convert a scalar to a vector. Just return the magnitude unchanged.

```
return magnitude
```